# How to escape double quote " in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to put double quotes in a String in Thymeleaf, I have something of the form:

```
<td th:text='${"Value of \"" + item + "\" is \"" + value + "\"."}'></td>
```

The result i want is:

```
<td>Value of "apple" is "1.5".</td>
```

But I get the following exception:

```
EL1065E: unexpected escape character.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible.  Something like this works:

```
th:text='|Value of "${item}" is "${value}".|'
```

I would personally write it like this:

```
th:text="${'Value of &quot;' + item + '&quot; is &quot;' + value + '&quot;.'}"
```

I think the reason there is no way to escape double quotes, is that thymeleaf is first parsing as xml/html (which has no escape other than `&quot;`) and then parsing as thymeleaf second which doesn't really have a chance to get at those strings.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know we could do it this way.