# Thymeleaf variable in string literal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm currently dev'ing a website based off a template (unfortunately) that I got. In this template we have the following piece of code:

```
<button class="product-gallery-popup hintT-left" data-hint="Click to enlarge" data-images='[
                        {"src": "${product.zoomedPhotoURL}", "w": 700, "h": 1100},
                        {"src": "/images/product/extra/zoom1.jpg", "w": 700, "h": 1100},
                        {"src": "/images/product/extra/zoom2.jpg", "w": 700, "h": 1100},
                        {"src": "/images/product/extra/zoom3.jpg", "w": 700, "h": 1100}
                    ]'><i class="far fa-expand"></i></button>
```

As you can probably guess, in the data-images tag of the button, I have one variable src link of an image. How can I make this dynamic based on the product in the model of the controller? I always get parsing exceptions or it treats it as a normal string, generating the wrong link.

Comment: You can use `th:data-images=` instead of `data-images=` - and that will create an HTML5 attribute called `data-images` which will be processed by Thymeleaf, and therefore inside of which you can place your `${product.zoomedPhotoURL}` expression.

Comment: For mixing the expression with all that literal text, you will need to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758513/how-to-escape-double-quote-in-thymeleaf), because your string literals include a lot of double-quotes. It will be awkward, but it can be done using the answer for that question.

Comment: Hey @andrewjames thanks for your answer. As you also indicated in your second reply, with the quotes it is quite akward and nearly impossible to do. With your first reply and another question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758513/how-to-escape-double-quote-in-thymeleaf I was able to figure it out. Thanks a lot!