# Escape double quotes inside single quoted text

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

With spring boot 3.0.1 and thymeleaf 3.1 in the below expression:

```
<a th:replace="~{fragments/paging :: paging(${totalPages}, ' Last >>', 'Last Page')}"></a>
```

I am trying to replace `' Last >>'` with `' <i class="fa-solid fa-forward-step"></i>'` and hence need to escape double-quotes.

I tried the suggestions and solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758513/how-to-escape-double-quote-in-thymeleaf/47758816#47758816), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758513/how-to-escape-double-quote-in-thymeleaf) and other SO threads but none of them seem working.

When I try using  `&quot;` the text appears as it while for other options I get parsing error. What I am missing? After trying so many options I am feeling clueless. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: It's not really clear what you say is wrong with `&quot;`.  When I run it with `&quot`, the [HTML appears correct to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrzY7.png).

Comment: I mean to say the text shows as it - `<i class="fa-solid fa-forward-step"></i>` instead of showing an FA icon.

Comment: That's just `th:utext` vs `th:text`.  Again, `&quot;` [appears to work as desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Cn9.png).